# Finding 3 constants in continuous random variable with absolute value

Tags: statistics

The probability density function of a continuous random variable $X$ that takes values in the interval $[0,4]$ has the graph given below [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrmJS.png)

(a)Find the value of $k$

(b)Given that $f(x)= a-b|x-c|,  0 \le x\le 4$

$0$, otherwise

Find the values of $a$,$b$ and $c$

I know how to solve (a) because  the total area under graph=$1$

${1\over2(2k)}+{1\over2(2k)}=1,k={1\over 2}$

But I don't know how to find the constants in (b)

Requesting guidance thanks in advance

Comment: Please use mathjax syntax

Comment: Think of the shape of the graph of $f(x)=-|x|$.  This is just a transformation of that graph by shifting and scaling.

Comment: Hint: note that the function given in b) is maximal at $x=c$.

Comment: You can use geometry, rather than calculus, to find $k$ so that the areas of the two triangles add to 1.

Answer (score 1):

so we have: $f(x)= a-b|x-c|,  0 \le x\le 4$

You already concluded that the max value is half, so $a= \frac{1}{2}$, and to make things equal $c=2$ (so that the 2nd term becomes zero at the max value).

Next note the constriction that the function value is $0$ at $x=0$. So: $a-b|-c|=0\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}-b|2|=0 \Rightarrow b=\frac{1}{4}$